# How to read an improperly formatted column from Excel using SAS

Tags: excel, sas

Before posting I tried Google but not a lot of help.

I have an **Excel file** with this value in the **`Opened_DT`** column: **1448300037,15**. Excel only displays a bunch of **######** characters instead of the date.

I have been given this file and do not know what actual output should the date format be. It should state the date an account has been opened with an institution.  I need to import this Excel column into a `SAS` data set, but this string drives me crazy :( I have tried bunch of conversion utilities,  and addons but no luck.

Can someone show me how to read this column using SAS?

Here is an example of [my Excel workbook](http://leteckaposta.cz/192523373)

Comment: Did you try widening the column?

Comment: yes. that was the first I did. Then tried to use different date formats, but no luck. Even importing to SAS did not help and SAS complains about this strange date column

Comment: Could you please share the file?

Comment: I added a data sample to the original question. thnx

Comment: It would be helpful if you can find out what date that number represents then it might be possible to work out how to convert

Comment: Can you guess a rough period from where this date might be? If 1448300037 is a SAS datetime value it would be 22NOV2005:17:33:57

Comment: @dperetin Does that count from 1960? I was thinking Unix - seconds from 1/1/1970 - but that gives 2015 and I assume it must be a past date......

Comment: @barryhoudini yes, sas datetime is number of seconds from midnight 1960-01-01

Comment: @dperetin the data should be from the period between 2003-2007. And that date looks actually pretty good. Can I ask how did you convert it and how it can be done in excel (other tool) so I can export it and use it in SAS? As SAS is not able to load the xls and gives me an error exactly on this column that it can't figure it out what's the date format. Thank you.

Comment: Sas datetime is just a number, so don't import it as a date. Import it as any number variable and then just format it to something like datetime20.

Answer (score 3):

From your sample it looks that initial data is wrong: this is what Excel 2007 shows me:

[image: Screenshot from Excel]

Indeed, actual value is too large to be `Date` - for today's date serial number is `41335`. Please make sure your application calculates correctly `Opening_DT` values.

As per [Excel specifications and limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291):

```
Latest date allowed for calculation         December 31, 9999
Largest amount of time that can be entered  9999:59:59
```

Serial for `December 31, 9999` is `2958465`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible that something else is encoded in that number? like exact date, minutes etc. The data is from an insurance institution and used as par of a thesis and should be imported to SAS, but that's not gonna happen before I crack this weird collumn. :(

Comment: @ryan I may only guess, but most likely you're right - this seems to be concatenated / badly formatted value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the column in your Excel worksheet was created using some technique that translated decimal points to commas.  The example value cited (**1448300037,15**) is equivalent to a SAS timestamp of `22NOV2005:17:33:57.15`.

If that value is legitimate and you want to turn this into a SAS data set, I suggest formatting the column as TEXT in Excel, saving it as a new workbook, and reading that new workbook into SAS with PROC IMPORT.  Then post-process the result to re-read that variable as a SAS datetime variable.  To illustrate:

```
proc import out=have
            datafile="path-to-workbook\workbook.xlsx"
            replace
            dbms=excel;
     sheet="sheetname";
run;

data want;
   set have(rename=(Open_DT=prevOpen_DT));
   format Open_DT datetime21.2;
   Open_DT = input(prevOpen_DT,numx13.2);
   drop prevOpen_DT;
run;
```

The `numx` SAS informat used in the `input` statement reads the character variable and interprets the comma as the decimal point.

Comment: @Bob_Duell - I assume that ryan's regional settings use comma as a decimal separator - that's the default for many European countries

Comment: @barryhoudini That likely explains why Ryan's Excel shows the `####` pattern; the workbook itself may have been created from a European region.  The point is that his Excel column appears to contain a SAS internal DATEIME value (the value to the right of the decimal is milliseconds). There is no Excel function to convert it to an Excel DATETIME value. Reformatting the column as `text` and processing it as shown will solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know anything about SAS, Bob....but isn't the value seconds (not milliseconds) since 1/1/1960? My answer shows a way to convert that in Excel - I assume it works as the result is the same one you suggested, i.e. 22-Nov-2005 17:33:57.15

Comment: @barryhoudini Yes, you are right; I misspoke about milliseconds, it is fractional seconds. And yes, SAS datetime values are seconds since 1960-01-01.  I didn't see your answer when replying before; I'm sure it will also work but similarly requires changing the workbook (inserting a new column?). Can't say which is "better", but I learned something about Excel from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that for your region decimal separators are commas so 1448300037,15 is a valid number......

If that represents the number of seconds from 1st Jan 1960 then in Excel you can convert to a valid date/time by adding the start date (1st Jan 1960) to your number expressed as days (which you can get by dividing by the number of seconds in a day), so with data in A2 use this formula

`=DATE(1960,1,1)+A2/86400`

and format as a date/time, e.g. `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm`

Answer (score 0):

Make the column width wider. Excel sometimes shows hashes if the data can't fit.

Comment: yes. that was the first I did. Then tried to use different date formats, but no luck. It looks like Excel not being able to understand what I want to convert/what format am I using :(